# Why doesn't the compiler enforce that sequencing rules are held?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, undefined-behavior

Statements like `int n6 = n1 + ++n1;` are undefined behavior because they violate the sequencing rules. But if they're a violation of the sequence rules, why doesn't the compiler just give a hard error? Other examples:

```
i = ++i + i++; // undefined behavior
i = i++ + 1; // undefined behavior (but i = ++i + 1; is well-defined)
f(++i, ++i); // undefined behavior
f(i = -1, i = -1); // undefined behavior
```

It seems in all of these cases the standard explicitly says it's undefined behavior, so it could just as easily say "the program is ill-formed" which will usually result in a hard diagnostic.

Comment: Should the compile be able to figure [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f11297b5b6e064c8) out?  It is the same thing but much harder to diagnose.

Comment: A hard error is a valid result of undefined behaviour, so making it UB allows compilers to reject it _if_ they can detect it (e.g. with `-Werror=sequence-point` or similar)

Comment: @JonathanWakely A hard error is only a valid result of undefined behaviour in code that would be executed at run time. `-Werror=sequence-point` can be very useful, but when using it, by design, GCC no longer conforms to the C++ standard. `int main() {} void f(int i) { ++i + ++i; }` is what C would call a strictly conforming program. (I'm not sure what the proper C++ term for it is.)

Comment: @hvd, good point. An omniscient compiler could still reject it in cases where it can prove it would be reached at run time. That's not very practically useful though.

Comment: Does this mean something like `i = ++i + i++` is a valid program?

Answer (score 4):

Because it's difficult for a compiler to produce a hard diagnostic here in the general case. You've shown a really contrived and obvious example, but the reality is usually more complex than this. It's easier just to say "don't do it, and the compiler doesn't have to tell you off for it either".

Comment: Perhaps a concrete example of something that a compiler won't be able to detect would be a good addition to your answer to help the OP. (Something like `++*p + ++*q` should do, when the compiler can't know whether `p == q`.)

Comment: Is it NP-hard or undecidable or something to ensure sequencing rules are held?

Comment: hvd's comment seems to contradict this answer.

Comment: @djechlin I'm agreeing with this answer.

Comment: @hvd sorry I just don't see how "Because it's difficult" is a valid answer in light of "-Werror=sequence-point does it." I guess this has little to do with your comment, although that's where I learned of the flag from.

Comment: @djechlin: "-Werror=sequence-point" does not do it, for the general case. Only for the "really contrived and obvious example".

Comment: @djechlin Oh, I thought you meant my comment on this answer, rather than my comment on the question. I suppose adding "without false positives" to this answer addresses your concerns. Adding a hard error for invalid code is trivial if you don't care about valid code getting rejected equally. :)

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, it's very hard to detect whether an arbitrary expression violates the sequencing rules.

```
int f(int *pa, int *pb) {
  return ++*pa + ++*pb;
}
```

It can have UB for reason other than sequencing depending on the input values, consider e.g. `f(0, 0)`, but when considering only sequencing, does this have defined behaviour?

There's not enough information to answer that question. It violates the sequencing rules only if `pa == pb`. There's nothing to rule that out, but equally, there's nothing to suggest that any code calls it like that.

If we can't tell, a compiler can't tell either. Therefore, it cannot be ill-formed, only undefined, and any diagnostics are left as a quality of implementation issue.

The fact that it's undefined at run-time, not ill-formed, then has another consequence: it means that it's only a problem if the code is ever executed. I gave an example in a comment:

```
int main() { }
void f(int i) { ++i + ++i; }
```

The function `f` has undefined behaviour, but the program as a whole does not, because the function `f` is never called. Because there is not and cannot be any rule in the C++ standard to disallow this, compilers are not allowed to issue error messages even for the simple cases.

However, compilers are always allowed to issue a warning (or any other non-fatal diagnostic) for any code, so useful compilers do try to detect this and let you know you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`-Werror=sequence-point` detects and emits compile error on the behavior you are talking about, but it produces false positives in the general case.

I do not know how easy it is to write general practical programs that conform to this flag (presumably hard enough to not make it a language requirement).

I also do not know in what sense it is computationally hard to verify sequence points validity (undecidable, NP-hard, etc). This would seem to impact the former question.

Comment: And as I commented on the question, causes valid programs to be rejected.

Comment: @hvd you clearly know more about this than anyone else on this question, can you post an answer?

Comment: I considered that initially, but felt that I wouldn't be able to add much to @PreferenceBean's answer. I'll try again to see if I can come up with something.

Comment: @djechlin I'm not an expert, but the gist of it is that "undefined behavior" means the program is not "ill-formed" so a hard diagnostic would imply rejecting compilation is in violation of the Standard, but now I'm confusing myself...

Comment: @hvd ok, brought my answer up to being accurate at least.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley dunno, is the issue false negatives?

Comment: I wouldn't say that, since `-Werror=sequence-point` is not claimed to find all sequence point related undefined behavior. The problem is that, for now, it is simply too difficult to detect, as PreferenceBean stated, and no tool that I'm aware of claims to be capable of it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley what does "too difficult" mean? Is it NP-hard or something?

Comment: @djechlin: I simply mean that nobody has been able to figure out how to do it, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @djechlin: hvd's indirection example's pretty good. It is actually impossible for the compiler to know whether his function has UB or not, for any given values of `pa` and `pb` -- because it does not know what those values are, and crucially whether they are the same or not, if that (say) depends on user input. Make this ill-formed and suddenly every compiler is non-compliant because there are ill-formed programs they simply cannot diagnose. This is a textbook occasion for calling it UB instead.